# Can I double reduce?

Tags: javascript

PROBLEM: I have a dataset in CSV format that has some key metrics I need to manipulate. I have regions, dates and sales volumes. I want to combine the similar regions together. I also want to combine the similar dates and add the sales volume per region per combined date.

SOLUTION:

```js
const tableNoHeader = table
         .split('\n')
         .map(line => line.split(','))
         .slice(1)
         .reduce((region, row) => {
            region[row[10]] = region[row[10]] || [];
            region[row[10]].push({
              weekOf: row[5],
              sales : parseFloat(row[8]) >= 0 
                         && parseFloat(row[9]) >= 0 
                            ? parseFloat(row[8]) + parseFloat(row[9]) 
                            : ""
              });
              return region;
           }, {});
```

I’ve successfully used reduce to combine all the duplicate regions together but now within each region I have duplicate dates and I want to have those reduced(?) as well.

Not sure if that’s possible or how to do this effectively...

Here is some sample data from the **CSV**:

```
First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Key, Role, Date, Unit Type 1, Unit Type 2, Units Sales 1, Units Sales 2, Region, Position, Hire
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 12, 2, West, Associate, 2017
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 7, 22, Central, Associate, 2019
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 21, 1, Central, Associate, 2019
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 4, 8, Central, Associate, 2012
Jake, Doe, Jake Doe, JakeDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 2, 2, West, Associate, 2019
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Without sample data this is a lot harder to contextualize.

Comment: There's nothing prohibiting using `reduce()` inside another `reduce()` callback function.

Comment: I think this code could already be simplified, combining 2 reduce is not forbidden, but there might be a way to merge them. but without example of the data processed, it remains impossible to show

Comment: without knowing data, it seems that `if(row[10].weekOf !== row[5]) { row[10].push(...) }` will eliminate duplicate dates.

Comment: Instead of making each region an Array make it a plain object, for which the keys will be weekOf value, and the value the sales. If required you can then iterate over the values of this tree to go back to your format if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/wby2f7hc/

Answer (score 2):

I think this is it ?

```js
//                0           1          2          3    4     5     6            7            8              9              10      11        12
const csvData = `First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Key, Role, Date, Unit Type 1, Unit Type 2, Units Sales 1, Units Sales 2, Region, Position, Hire
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 12, 2, West, Associate, 2017
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 7, 22, Central, Associate, 2019
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 21, 1, Central, Associate, 2019
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 4, 8, Central, Associate, 2012
Jake, Doe, Jake Doe, JakeDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 2, 2, West, Associate, 2019'`

const tableNoHeader = csvData
  .split('\n').slice(1) 
  .map(line =>
    {  //  0          1         2         3    4     5       6          7          8            9            10      11        12
    let [ FirstName, LastName, FullName, Key, Role, weekOf, UnitType1, UnitType2, UnitsSales1, UnitsSales2, region, Position, Hire]
        = line.split(/, |,/)
    return ({ region, weekOf, sales : (+UnitsSales1) + (+UnitsSales2) })
    })     
  .reduce((res,{region,weekOf,sales}) =>
    {
    res[region] = res[region] || []
    let regWeek = res[region].find(x=>x.weekOf === weekOf )
    if (!regWeek) res[region].push({ weekOf, sales })
    else          regWeek.sales += sales
    return res
    }, {})
console.log( tableNoHeader )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Ctsa3 As you see, there is no needs to use a double reduce to  sum your sales per weeks ;)

Comment: Waking up so I might be missing something, But... isn't running `.find()` inside every steps of the reduce exponentially worse than doing a simple reduce?

Comment: @Kaiido it is because the PO ask for a result with arrays, for each region, which themselves will require as many reduces which will force them to have as many find as my current code, but for a more penalizing result with all these reduces. if the PO is looking for a higher performance then it will change the structure of your regions into objects and not arrays. and anyway in this case also we no longer need to nest the reduces for each region

Comment: @Kaiido how can you do a second reduce for everything ? the actual output is not an array and you need to regroup any  array of each region on weekOf and sales ?

Comment: Yes, my bad sorry. Still that would be linear, while `find()` is exponential in worst case.

Comment: @Kaiido I posted a second double answer below, it is probably faster than the find()

Answer (score 1):

To add a cumulation per date: before your `push`, we need to check if `row[5]` is already listed as a `weekOf` in the region...

```
const tableNoHeader = table
          .split('\n')
          .map(line => line.split(','))
          .slice(1)
          .reduce((region, row) => {
            const region1 = region[row[10]] || [],
            sale1 = parseFloat(row[8]) >= 0 && parseFloat(row[9]) >= 0 ? parseFloat(row[8]) + parseFloat(row[9]) : "";

            for(var i = 0; i < region1.length; i++) {
              if region1[i].weekOf === row[5] {
                region1[i].sales += sale1; // make sure it's numeric if not ""
                region1[i].sales = region1[i].sales ? + region1[i].sales : "";
                break;
              }
            }
            if(i === region1.length) region1.push({
              weekOf: row[5],
              sales: sale1
            });
            region[row[10]] = region1;
            return region;
          }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, as **Kaiido** reminded me of the idea of placing a second reduce after the first, here is a second double proposition:

the first One idea is about changing the result structure (anything is objects) and ther is no needs of a second reduce

```js
//                0           1          2          3    4     5     6            7            8              9              10      11        12
const csvData = `First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Key, Role, Date, Unit Type 1, Unit Type 2, Units Sales 1, Units Sales 2, Region, Position, Hire
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 12, 2, West, Associate, 2017
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 7, 22, Central, Associate, 2019
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 21, 1, Central, Associate, 2019
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 4, 8, Central, Associate, 2012
Jake, Doe, Jake Doe, JakeDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 2, 2, West, Associate, 2019'`

const tableNoHeader = csvData
  .split('\n').slice(1) 
  .map(line =>
    {  //  0          1         2         3    4     5       6          7          8            9            10      11        12
    let [ FirstName, LastName, FullName, Key, Role, weekOf, UnitType1, UnitType2, UnitsSales1, UnitsSales2, region, Position, Hire]
        = line.split(/, |,/)
    return ({ region, weekOf, sales : (+UnitsSales1) + (+UnitsSales2) })
    })     
  .reduce((res,{region,weekOf,sales}) =>
    {
    res[region] = res[region] || {}
    res[region][weekOf] = res[region][weekOf] || 0
    res[region][weekOf] += sales
    return res
    }, {})
console.log(  tableNoHeader )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

this second solution is the same, but with a second retuce to transform the previous result to the same structure of my first post, but have nothing to do with an idea of grouping values.

```js
//                0           1          2          3    4     5     6            7            8              9              10      11        12
const csvData = `First Name, Last Name, Full Name, Key, Role, Date, Unit Type 1, Unit Type 2, Units Sales 1, Units Sales 2, Region, Position, Hire
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 12, 2, West, Associate, 2017
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 7, 22, Central, Associate, 2019
Jane, Doe, Jane Doe, JaneDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 21, 1, Central, Associate, 2019
John, Doe, John Doe, JohnDoe, Sales, 01-Mar-21, Commercial, Commercial, 4, 8, Central, Associate, 2012
Jake, Doe, Jake Doe, JakeDoe, Sales, 22-Feb-21, Commercial, Commercial, 2, 2, West, Associate, 2019'`

const tableNoHeader = csvData
  .split('\n').slice(1) 
  .map(line =>
    {  //  0          1         2         3    4     5       6          7          8            9            10      11        12
    let [ FirstName, LastName, FullName, Key, Role, weekOf, UnitType1, UnitType2, UnitsSales1, UnitsSales2, region, Position, Hire]
        = line.split(/, |,/)
    return ({ region, weekOf, sales : (+UnitsSales1) + (+UnitsSales2) })
    })     
  .reduce((res,{region,weekOf,sales},i,{[i+1]:nxt}) =>
    {
    res[region] = res[region] || {}
    res[region][weekOf] = res[region][weekOf] || 0
    res[region][weekOf] += sales
    if (nxt) return res
    else return Object.keys(res).reduce((x,rg)=>
      {
      x[rg] = Object.entries(res[rg]).map(([k,v])=>({weekOf:k,sales:v}))
      return x
      } ,{})
    }, {})

console.log( tableNoHeader )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```